# VCS checkout based on a file

Tags: python, scripting, cvs, vcs-checkout

I want to checkout a bunch of files from a CVS server.
Is there a way I can pass cvs command a file name which contains files I want to checkout
Is there another way of accomplishing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a bash-style shell:

```
cvs co $(< myfile)
```

Where `myfile` contains the list of files you want to check out.

If you're talking about *modules* instead of files, Oliver Giesen's answer will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the docs for the `CVSROOT/modules` file and then define a regular module like this:

```
MyModule folder file1 file2 file3 [...]
```

You would then be able to do:

```
cvs co MyModule
```